# Displaying values of a view to another view (MVC)

Tags: html, model-view-controller, view, row, display

I have a table in a View with some Car details on it. After I click 'Rent' button, to redirect me to another View and display the data of the selected row there. Using the button that I already have on the code, I am only able to display details of that row in the URL but they are not being displayed on the page.

**Here is my ListOfCars View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<CarDataAccess.Car>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "List";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>ListCars</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/OnClick.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>
@*<p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Post")
    </p>*@



<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.model)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.make)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.avaStart)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.avaEnd)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.model)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.make)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.avaStart)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.avaEnd)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>

            <td>

            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Rent", "Payment", new { id = item.Id })</td>




            </td>




        </tr>

    }

</table>



<div>
    <a href="http://localhost:6664/User/Login">Login</a>
</div>
```

**And here is the other View where I want the row to be displayed:**

```html
@model IEnumerable<CarDataAccess.Car>


@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "Payment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Payment</title>

</head>
<body>
    <table class="paymenttable">

        
    </table>

    

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller's code:**

```
namespace RentCarApplication.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    BookCarDBEntities db = new BookCarDBEntities();
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {

        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ListCars()
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        var cars = db.Cars.ToList();

        return View(cars);
    }
 public ActionResult Payment(int id)
    {
       using (BookCarDBEntities entities = new BookCarDBEntities())
        {
            var entity = entities.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (entities != null)
            {
                return View(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Not Found");
            }

        }






    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does the controller look like? Are you showing all the code for the Rent Car view? What model are you passing the that view? The View expects IEnumerable<Car>. Wouldn't that view be a single car model.

Comment: @Haldo I have just added the controller, you can check it out. I dont know instead of IEnumerable<CarDataAccess.Car> what should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller action `Payment(int id)` you are passing a single entity of type `CarDataAccess.Car` to the view (the line in your code `entities.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id)` gets a single entity from the database).

The `Payment` view expects a collection of type `IEnumerable<CarDataAccess.Car>`.  You can see this on the first line of the view `@model IEnumerable<CarDataAccess.Car>`. Change this to just `@model CarDataAccess.Car` and see if that solves the problem.

Update the view to this:

```
@model CarDataAccess.Car 

@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "Payment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Payment</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        @* access model properties here *@ 
        <span>@Model.Id</span>


    </body>
</html>
```

There is an error in your controller too.  Check that the `Car` entity is not null, not the database context (`entities`):

```
public ActionResult Payment(int id)
{
   using (BookCarDBEntities entities = new BookCarDBEntities())
    {
        var entity = entities.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        if (entity != null)    // check if entity is null, not entities
        {
            return View(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

There is another issue in your controller too - you have declared multiple instances of your database context (`BookCarDBEntities`).  It is best to wrap your database context in `using` statements like you did in the Payment method.  Do the same for the `ListCars` method and remove `BookCarDBEntities db = new BookCarDBEntities();` from the top of the controller.  If you wrap the context in using statements then that ensures the context is properly disposed of and cleaned up by the garbage collector.

The ListCars method should look like:

```
public ActionResult ListCars()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    var cars = new List<CarDataAccess.Car>();
    using (var db = new BookCarDBEntities())
    {
        cars = db.Cars.ToList();
    } 
    return View(cars);
}
```

Comment: Wow it was a really simple mistake that I didnt think of. Thanks a lot man, I really appreciate it!

Comment: btw do you have any suggestions about this: I want after clicking Pay on Payment view ,those data to be deleted from that table where they are currently and posted at another table?

Comment: It depends on your exact requirements. I often prefer to set a flag on the table rather than delete. You could have an `Active` column which is set to false instead of deleting the row. Or you could actually delete the data and do something like this in your delete controller action: `using (CarBookDBEntities db = new CarBookDBEntities()) { var carToDelete = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id); db.Cars.Remove(carToDelete); db.CarsPaid.Add(carToDelete); db.SaveChanges(); }` assuming the new table is called CarsPaid.

Comment: actually, I was trying the same way before but it shows an error saying "Cannot convert from CarDataAccess.Car to CarDataAccess.Booking"

Comment: You need to convert `Car` to `Booking` before saving to the `Bookings` table. You will need to create a method which takes a `Car` and returns a `Booking`. Then you'd do something like `var booking = CreateNewBooking(carToDelete); db.Bookings.Add(booking);`

Comment: struggling with that method that does the conversion :/

Comment: The method should accept `Car` as a parameter. Inside the method create a new `Booking` by something like: `var booking = new Booking();`. Copy the property values from the `Car` you input to the new `Booking` object eg `booking.CarId = car.Id; booking.Price = car.Price; ` for the shared properties. Then return the `booking` you just created. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am still having problems, its not working:                                                using (BookCarDBEntities db = new BookCarDBEntities())
                {
                    var carToDelete = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                    var book = CreateNewBooking(carToDelete);
                    db.Bookings.Add(booking);
                    
                    db.Cars.Remove(carToDelete);
                    
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return View(book);
                }

Comment: @BurimSyla you should post a new question with details of any errors if you're still having issues :-)

Comment: I have just created a new questions, can you check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712157/deleting-in-one-table-and-copying-to-the-other-one-mvc