# ASP.NET MVC Deleting row from one table after copying it to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, copy

I have a case where I am trying to Delete one item from a table but before doing that I want to copy it to another table.

**Here is my Delete method:**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, Car car)
    {
        try
        {
           using (BookCarDBEntities db = new BookCarDBEntities())
            {
                var carToDelete = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                var book = CreateNewBooking(carToDelete);
                db.Bookings.Add(book);

                db.Cars.Remove(carToDelete);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return View(book);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex + "error");
        }
    }
```

**And here is a method which does the conversion from 'Car' table to 'Booking' table:**

```
 private object CreateNewBooking(Car car)
    {
        var bookingCreated = new Booking
        {
            id = car.Id,
            model = car.model,
            make = car.make,
            price = car.price,
            location = car.location
        };

        return bookingCreated;
    }
```

The problem is that I get an error:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException': The entity type Booking is not part of the model for the current context.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So, what is the issue? ??

Comment: What errors are you getting? Try changing the create method to return a Booking: `private Booking CreateNewBooking(Car car){}`. There is also a typo in your code:  you're using `booking` to delete but its declared as `book`.

Comment: I made the changes and still it shows this error as soon as I hit Delete: "The view 'System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type Booking is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: @Haldo any idea what is it?

Comment: @BurimSyla try googling the exception to find out what it means. Does the table Bookings exist? The exception suggests it doesn't exist. Check out some tutorials on entity framework and MVC. Here's one using MVC, EF and code first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Haldo I have the table but I dont understand why is it showing it like that, for the other table it doesnt show any errors like that.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? Perhaps EF lost the reference/connection to that object. You could go to the edmx and select Update model from database, or try deleting `Bookings` from the edmx file and re-adding it.

Comment: Please show the `BookCarDBEntities` class

Comment: Fix it! @Haldo you are right, I renamed an attribute and that was not updated to entity framework so I had to do "Update from Database" and then Rebuild so it fixed. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You managed to fix the error (in the comments) but I'll post the solution here for others.

The error:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException': The entity type Booking is not part of the model for the current context.

can be caused for a couple of reasons.

1. The entity has become detached or has somehow lost its reference
   within the entity framewowrk. This can be resolved by refreshing the
   entities.  Go to the edmx file, right-click on the designer surface
   and selecting `Update model from database`. If that still fails,
   delete the entity (or all entities) in the designer and then update
   model from database.
2. If the table/entity does not exist. In this case create the table/entity and
   update the entities.
3. Then Rebuild after you have updated from database.